# Do it on an int or uint type of data! What happens to the operation

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, esp32, esp-idf

I'm having an issue with the ESP32-IDF auto-generated code, where the following code is used to flip the pin level by default in an example code of a flashing light

```c
static uint8_t led_state = 0;

...

led_state = !led_state;  toggle the pin state
```

how to understand the '!' operation here

I write a small program like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t i = 2;
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    i = !i;
    printf("i toggled\n");
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    i = !i;
    printf("i toggled\n");
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
i = 2
i toggled
i = 0
i toggled
i = 1
```

Comment: `!` is a logical negation. It will turn a `0`value into `1`, and non-`0` to `0`. Periodically negating the same variable will make it alternating between `0` and `1`.

Comment: "how to understand the '!' operation here" The `uint8_t` in that example is just to be regarded as a bool. It's sloppy code, which tends to be the standard for these kind of Arduino:ish platforms.

Answer (score 4):

`!` is the logical NOT operator.

- If it's operand isn't equal to zero (i.e. if it's a true value), it returns `0` (a false value).
- If it's operand is equal to zero (i.e. if it's a false value), it returns `1` (a true value).

[C logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical)

---

If you need to set a specific bit, you can use a shift.

```c
led_state = !led_state;            // Toggle the state.
uint8_t bitmask = led_state << 1;  // 1 or 0 => 2 or 0.
```

If you want to toggle a specific bit, you can use an exclusive or.

```c
bitmask ^= 1 << 2;                 // Toggle the second bit directly.
```

Comment: Notably `led_state << n` where `led_state` is `uint8_t` is most definitely incorrect code on a 32 bit MCU such as the one referred to here. `led_state` would have to be of type `uint32_t`.